# Integrity constraints to make sur two columns contain same values for two related tables

Tags: oracle, constraints, database-integrity

I have two tables in my oracle database.

```
+--------+                     +---------+    
+ data   + --1..0-------0..n --+   PAQ   +  
+--------+                     +---------+
```

PAQ has many data.

Here is an example of how they're made:

```sql
create table data {
data_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
value number,
data_date date,
E_FLAG char,
paq_id number,
primary key(data_id),
foreign key(paq_id) references paq.paq_id
}

create table paq {
paq_id number generated by default as identity,
E_FLAG char,
...
primary key(paq_id)
}
```

there is a column which is duplicated called E_FLAG.

I want to insure the following:
**If data1 belongs to paq1 then data1.E_FLAG == paq1.E_FLAG.** using integrity constraints in oracle.

I this possible?

Comment: Can you please give us the table structure and some example, how are the two tables related , do they have column or columns on which you can join and check the data ? Is there a driver table ? what happens when you add a row 1st time in a table , how do you want to handle that ?

Comment: I added more details, what i want is every time i add a row in data, if this row has a paq associated to it then i have to make sure that E_FLAG of data and paq have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer would be to normalize the data model and not duplicate the column in the `data` table.

That said, if you create a unique index on `paq`

```
create unique index uniq_paq_flag
    on paq( paq_id, e_flag );
```

You can then create a foreign key constraint on that combination that ensures that the `e_flag` value matches

```
alter table data
  add constraint fk_match_flag 
    foreign key( paq_id, e_flag ) 
    references paq( paq_id, e_flag );
```

Comment: Yes I agree with this, I'm working in a project where i actually had to denormalize. the question that i asked is very simplified and addresses the core of my problem.